# amazon rds - problems with creating DB instance

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, visual-studio-2013, amazon-rds, rds

I want to connect my sql DB to amazon rds.
When I tried to launch DB instance threw visual studio I got this error message:
[image: Aws error]

How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error message this is what I can guess for. As you are launching the RDS instance via the Visual Studio SDK; looks like the config / option is set to launch in a VPC; may your AWS Profile is configured for the default region has only one VPC which doesn't have Public SubNet.

These are the things you can try and then you may succeed launching an RDS instance

1. Change the config in Visual Studio to launch RDS outside VPC i.e. Non VPC based RDS
2. Create an Internet gatway, attach that to a subnet in VPC

Links

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSToolkitVS/latest/UserGuide/tkv-launch-rds-instance-sql-svr.html